# Remove duplication in lines from lsit, without modifcations in other lines

Tags: python, list, duplicates, line

I have a large text file full of phrase lines.

I don't want phrase lines with duplicated words showing anymore in the text file and reading previous forum questions I tried so solve the problem with this real simple code, but it doesn't work:

```
with open('V frasi.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        \b(\w+)\s+\1\b
        print(re.sub("ing$",'ring',line.strip()))
```

Previously I found this lookslike italian code thanks to AI, but I noticed modification in the word order of results:

```
def rimuovi_parole_duplicate(frase):
    parole = frase.split()  # Divide la frase in parole
    parole_senza_duplicate = list(set(parole))  # Rimuove le parole duplicate
    parole_senza_duplicate.sort(key=parole.index)  # Mantiene l'ordine originale delle parole
    frase_senza_duplicate = ' '.join(parole_senza_duplicate)  # Ricrea la frase senza duplicati
    return frase_senza_duplicate

# Apri il file in modalità lettura
with open('input.log', 'r') as file:
    frasi = file.readlines()

# Rimuovi eventuali spazi bianchi o caratteri di nuova riga
frasi = [frase.strip() for frase in frasi]

# Apri un file di log in modalità scrittura per registrare i risultati
with open('result.txt', 'w') as log_file:
    # Rimuovi le parole duplicate da ciascuna frase e stampa le frasi risultanti
    for i, frase in enumerate(frasi, 1):  # Use enumerate to track the line number (starting from 1)
        frase_senza_duplicate = rimuovi_parole_duplicate(frase)
        print(frase_senza_duplicate)  # Print to console
        log_file.write(frase_senza_duplicate + '\n')  # Write to the log file
```

Can you help me to find the better coding solution?
It came up the second code was actually working, so I added a file txt for outpoot too.
I leave it here for everybody in his final version good for my task.

Thanks

Comment: i am getting correct result using same code.

Comment: Hi, Suman. You mean the second one?

Comment: I checked and it's true, maybe this morning when I used it I made some mistake creating the text lines file.

Sorry, I will leave the post anyway so anyone can use the scrypt, if mod likes to!